# Comparing two instances of build artifact using same SVN revision

Tags: svn, compare

If I build an artifact at two different times, using the same SVN revision, can I not rely on the two instances being binarily equal? (Same tools, compilers, etc.)  KDiff3 is showing differences, so apparently I cannot, but I would like to understand why, or what I might do differently.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by artifact? Generally, often two builds from the same resources may not be binary-equal if they encode some information on the build environment (e.g. the build date). From svn, you will always get the same data for a fixed revision.

Comment: This depends upon your build process and, like @MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper noted, what it may inject into those artifacts. If your build process is deterministic, then it will produce the same output from the same revision.

Comment: thanks.  I thought it was deterministic, but the artifact (in this case an EXE) does not compare exactly. I guess I'll have to look more carefully.